# Symfony/Api-Platform - How do I expose a CRUD-Operation for the addItem/removeItem functions of a ManyToMany-Relation?

Tags: symfony, collections, orm, crud, api-platform.com

I have an Angular Web-App that sends requests to exposed CRUD-Endpoints of a Symfony/Api-Platform API. The basic functionality is that a **User** can favorite **Items**.

So the relationship is: Many **Users** may favorite many **Items**.
I want to add (e.g. favorite) or remove (e.g. un-favorite) just one or more **Items** with a single request, but that seems quite complicated.

Currently I can only update the **Items**-Array of **User** by sending a PUT-request with a body that looks like this:

```
 {
    items: [iri1, iri2]
 }
```

Now If I want to add or delete an **Item** the whole collection needs to be resent:

```
 {
    items: [iri1, iri2, iri3]
 }
```

Symfony/Api-Platform does not allow direct CRUD exposure of add/remove functions, but I am looking for a way to still expose that functionality, because it appears somewhat inefficient to reset the whole collection, especially with huge amounts.

Now I have 2 questions:

1: Is Doctrine smart enough to know which **Item** has been added or removed from the passed request items-property? As far as I know Doctrine "updates" an ArrayCollection by calling setElements(), overriding the whole set. But maybe I am missing stuff and only the add/remove functions for additional/missing **Items** will be called. It is quite redundant to re-set **Items** that have already persisted to the database...

2: How do I implement a way to efficiently add/remove an **Item** from the **User** items-property, preferably through something Entity-Related e.g. a custom DataPersister or, if possible, Annotations.

Comment: Doctrine is smart enough yes. It uses proxy objects before it calculates any db statements. You can view this by creating an event subscriber on the postPersist and have access to the LifecycleEventArgs and UnitOfWork.. How did you setup your relation? If you used `bin/console make:entity` with type set to `relation` it would have guided you through and auto generated the *addItem* and *removeItem* methods within your User entity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yea i setup the entity through the maker-bundle, and it did add the _addItem_ and _removeItem_ functions. I needed a way to make their functionality accessible through the CRUD-API. I am mainly trying to avoid too many database-calls, and my assumption is that setting the **Items**-Collection makes Doctrine iterate and validate _all_ the items, not just the new ones. I could not find any answer in the docs, but I will try and check tomorrow with an eventSubscriber, maybe it will provide some answers

Comment: You can use a PATCH on your User resource and only submit items iri in body. You also need to expose items with a GET item endpoint so api-platform can understand iri. I use this pattern because I don't need to add specific code and a voter is already define for this endpoint.

Comment: @AdrienChinour thanks for the suggestion, I will try that, but as I understand it the PATCH-Method overwrites just those entity-properties present in the request-body. In Api-Platform a PUT-Request provides nearly identical functionality, as you can provide only properties you want to update. My issue is a bit more deeper, because I want to update a collection without re-sending the whole collection, just items that should be added or removed, but I feel like that is only possible through a custom persister or controller.

Comment: Ok sorry, I misunderstood your question. Yep, I suggest you create a custom PUT operation like /users/{id}/add-items and a body with IRIs to add items. Same for delete. But you have to create a custom controller and add all necessary configurations in your ApiResource annotation.